# Child component not rerendering when state change is triggered by its sibling

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

There are two child components (L1 and L2). Both render text and a button. When the button in L1 gets pressed it changes the text of L1 (works fine in code below). When the button in L2 gets pressed it changes the text of L2 (works also fine in code below).

The L1 component additionally has a second button though to also change the text that is located inside the other component L2. This is where my code does not work anymore. The same function used still gets called and the state value is changed but the L2 component will never rerender/its text stays the same.

PARENT:

```
export const Parent = ({ hours, day, location, context }) => {

const numItemsToShow:number = 12;
const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState<any>({
    showMoreX: false,
    showMoreY: false,
    showMoreAmountX: 50 * numItemsToShow,
    showMoreAmountY: 50 * numItemsToShow,
    showMoreAmountTotalX: 0 //x cannot be set to auto => need to know total width
});


const doShowMoreX = (e) => {
    console.log('1')
    setShowMore((prevState) => {
        return {...prevState, showMoreX: !showMore.showMoreX};
    });
}

const doShowMoreY = (e) => {
    console.log('2')
    setShowMore((prevState) => { //PROBLEM: When called by L1, the Text in L2 never changes even though state changes - when called by L2 its all fine/text changes
        return {...prevState, showMoreY: !showMore.showMoreY};
    });
}


return (
    <>
    <ErrorBoundary>
        {
            (context === 'detailed') ?
            <L2 day={day} hours={hours} location={location} state={showMore} doShowMoreY={doShowMoreY}></L2> :
            <L1 day={day} hours={hours} location={location} state={showMore} doShowMoreX={doShowMoreX} doShowMoreY={doShowMoreY}></L1>
        }
    </ErrorBoundary>
</>
)
}
```

L1 (CHILD 1)

```
export const L1 = ({ day, hours, location, state, doShowMoreX, doShowMoreY }) => {
const {showMoreX, showMoreAmountX, showMoreAmountTotalX} = state;

return (
    <div>
        {
            <div>
                <div>{(showMoreX) ? 'Some Output L1' : '-'}</div>
                <button onClick={doShowMoreX}>Change Output L1</button><br/>
                <button onClick={doShowMoreY}>Change Output L2</button> <!-- PROBLEM: L2 Text never changes even though doShowMoreY-function is called and state value is changed -->
            </div>
        }

    </div>
)
}
```

L2 (CHILD 2)

```
export const L2 = ({ day, hours, location, state, doShowMoreY }) => {
const { showMoreY, showMoreAmountY } = state;
return (
    <div>
        {
            <div>
                <div>{(showMoreY) ? 'Some Output L2' : '-'}</div>
                <button onClick={doShowMoreY}>Change Output L2</button>
            </div>
        }

    </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why my child component could not update its sibling component through the common parent component was the conditional statement inside the render-method of the common parent component.

```
return (
    <>
        <ErrorBoundary>
            {
            (context === 'detailed') ? //context value was the same and thus child never rerendered
            <L2 day={day} hours={hours} location={location} state={showMore} doShowMoreY={doShowMoreY}></L2> :
            <L1 day={day} hours={hours} location={location} state={showMore} doShowMoreX={doShowMoreX} doShowMoreY={doShowMoreY}></L1>
            }
        </ErrorBoundary>
    </>
)
```

I still needed that conditional statement though and thus I ended up checking the updated value directly inside the child using redux (same would work with react context API).